# How to change the tab bar background image to transparent image in ios sdk

Tags: ios

How to change tab bar **background** `transparent` image?
I am using `ios sdk 6.1`, i want to change application tab bar with `transparent` image.

Comment: means you want to hide it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily able to change the "tab bar background image",
Just Follow this code...

```
[yourTabBarOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBack.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks But i want transparent tabbar Controlar tab bar, [yourTabBarOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBack.png"]]; its only transparent tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a tab bar transparent is by setting the tab bar background image to a transparent image in the interface builder. 
You can get a transparent png image whose height and width is equal to the tab bar's from the net.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
[yourTabBarOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBack.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks But i want transparent tab bar, i also try with transparent image..
[tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"]]; like tabbar.png is a transparent image. but that show me white tabb bar.

Comment: Yes so just put transparent background image there!

Comment: @NitinGohel No I did not copied, You can view the link the other user has given below and Jugal can you please tell that why you did Minus to KesaVan and Plus for me.!

Comment: after trying with transparent image it show me white tabar... no dear i did not given minus to kesavan..